# Can't use dojo/query unless its in global

Tags: javascript, dojo

This is actually my first question in Stack (long time listener and all that).

I'm fairly new to Javascript in general and certainly new to Dojo. Been racking my brains for ages on this, but can't see what i'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to get query to work through this code to return all the `<p>` tags in the DOM. All well and good.

```
define ([
"dojo/dom",
"dojo/query"
], function (dom) {
return {
    changeParagraphs: function() {
        var nodeList = dom.query('p');
        console.log(nodeList);
    }
   }
});
```

Excuse the layout, still getting used to this.
If I call query as I have here...

```
require(["custom/q3",
         "dojo/domReady!",
         "dojo/query"], function(myObject){
    myObject.changeParagraphs();
})
```

I get an object has no method query error.

If instead of

> var nodeList = dom.query('p')

I call...

> var nodeList = dojo.query('p')

All is well. Why? I know its bad practice to use global (in any language really), but what is it i'm doing wrong? I've no intention of using global!

I imagine i'm most likely wasting people's time here, but I've been banging my head against the keyboard for hours now. It's mostly likely something really obvious!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `object has no method query` is a hint as to the problem.  The `dojo/dom` module has no query method.  Instead, you need to expose the `dojo/query` method in your define function callback:

```
define(["dojo/dom", "dojo/query"], function (dom, query) {
    return {
        changeParagraphs: function () {
            var nodeList = query('p');
            console.log(nodeList);
        }
    }
});
```

Then in your require:

```
require(["custom/q3", "dojo/domReady!"], function (myObject) {
    myObject.changeParagraphs();
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response. I'll be looking at this later on tonight so i'll get back to you. I'm sure your answer is most likely correct though :)
So when I was attempting to use it when it was attached to my object, I _should_ have been accessing it directly?

Comment: Just checked it and it worked great (like I doubted it!)
Thanks a lot. Needed to step back. Cheers again for the help!

Comment: @Galatoni Almost every Dojo 1.9 module (e.g. `foo/bar/baz`) is designed so that it creates a single object, array, or number, etc. when used, all hopefully without any side-effects or global variables. When the module-loader finishes getting all those payloads, it passes them to your function in the same order in which you listed the module names. So in BuffaloBuffalo's example, you *could* rewrite it as `function(foo,bar)` and `bar('p')` if you really wanted. (It's just not good style.)